# Custom developer setup with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I currently have a Vagrant vm with a typical web setup (apache, php, etc).  The actual web repo is checked out onto the my local machine, and accessed through synced folders and forwarded apache ports  (like http://127.0.0.1:4567/web).  The question is, how do I make this work for a team, as opposed to just me?  Since you have to sync folders, how is it possible for multiple devs to connect to one VM and sync folders?

I initially thought sharing the Vagrantfile would be all that is needed, but the Vagrantfile is agnostic to all apt-get commands and apache/php/node etc setup.  I don't want devs to have to worry about running those.

Comment: Why do you want to have a single VM for all developers on your team?

Comment: @Alik It doesn't have to be the same vm.  I'm just not understanding what the best way is for me to maintain a vm template (and update periodically) that others can use for their own localhost development and keep unified apt-get packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [Vagrant provisioning](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/) is for.

Vagrant allows you to automatically alter configuration of a box or install additional software packages as a part of the first `vagrant up` process. Moreover, you can provision your system with  various configuration management systems: Chef, Puppet, Ansible, CFEngine. Or you can simply use shell scripts.

Sitepoint offers a good tutorial on provisioning Ubuntu 14.04 box with bash scripts to install nginx, PHP-FPM and MySQL. [Read it](http://www.sitepoint.com/vagrantfile-explained-setting-provisioning-shell/). Later you might want to move to configuration management systems.

Take a look at [Phansible project](http://phansible.com/) which generates Ansible provisionings for PHP-based projects. Puppet provisioning for PHP-projects can be generated via [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/). They will give you an idea how to use configuration management with Vagrant and might be used as s template for your Vagrantfile.

I always try to craft my Vagrantfiles carefully (provisioning, synced folder, for example, maps host's `./src/public` onto `/var/www/html/` on guest machine, port forwards and so on) so I can put them into project's root under version control. Later when my teammate clones project's repo on his machine he can issue `vagrant up` right away and get a fully functional development environment.

The only problem I haven't solved yet is updating existing VMs when new dependencies are added to projects. Now we update provisioning scripts and if developers encounter errors they manually reprovision their VMs by using `vagrant reload --provision`.

P.S. I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546558/how-do-i-automate-dependency-installation-after-pulling-code-from-repository) regarding this problem

Comment: this looks exactly like what I am looking for.  For us, it might involve shell scripts.  The main things we customize are the etc hosts file, apache vhosts, telling apache and php which libraries/modules to add on after install.  Typical stuff, but if puppet or chef can do that, that would save some time instead of writing up a big shell script.