# How do I automate dependency installation after pulling code from repository?

Tags: version-control, dependencies, vagrant, development-environment

My collegue and I develop a small Python application. We use Vagrant to set up development environments.

Suppose my collegue introduces a new feature into the application. Feature's implementation requires a new python dependency (3rd party package) and the dependency itself needs some system libraries. If I do not read through all pulled commits carefully I can miss, that some systems libraries have to be installed prior running the project.

Of course we update `Vagrantfile` to install such non-python dependencies during provisioning, so if someone clones project's repository and issues `vagrant up` he will get a fully working development environment, but what shoud I do to automate updates in my *existing* environment?

How should we indicate, that a new dependency (python or non-python) was added and we need to install it by firing a specific command?

**UPD** I can try and run the application and if I encounter any errors it is a sign to reprovision my vagrant box, but it seems tedious to me to test a feature by hands and run provisioning scripts later

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this with Ruby as well. We used Bundler, which is a dependency management system for Ruby. If I pulled in new code, ran it and got funky exceptions saying that a certain dependency was missing, I just knew it was time for a `bundle install` from the command line. The solution to your problem is the same. If you run the code and get errors saying a dependency is missing, your default response to that exception should be to `vagrant up` on the command line, and try again.

Barring that, sending an email to your teammates with instructions about the new or updated dependency is a good way to go, especially if a `vagrant up` is insufficient to resolve the missing or incorrect dependency.